# Wordpress menu structure change in css file

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have used the wordpress twenty eleven theme for my website. Now i want to crate a dropdown menu for my site. By default wordpress have the dropdown menu facility. Now when i hover on the main menu i got the sub-menu part. For example :-

I have a main menu like :-
 Home | About | Contact

When i hover on the about menu it show the sub menus of "about" menu like

Home | About | Contact

```
   Our Services

   History

   Our Staff
```

when i hover on the history menu it display the sub menu of History Menu like bellow:-

Home | About | Contact

```
   Our Services

   History

      History 1
      History 2
      History 3

   Our Staff
```

but i want to display the submenu of History, when i hover on About menu. If i hover on the  About menu it should display like bellow :-

Home | About | Contact

```
   Our Services

   History

      History 1
      History 2
      History 3

   Our Staff
```

Please help me to get the output in the wordpress menu.

```
#access {
  background: #00ADEE; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 915px;
}
#access ul {
  font-size: 11px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#access li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#access a {
  color: #eee;
  display: block;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding: 4px 9px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(images/menu-border.png);
  background-position: right 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
#access ul ul {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11px;
  width: 252px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border: 1px solid #00AEEF;
}
#access ul ul li {
}
#access ul ul ul {
  left: 23%;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
}
#access ul ul ul li{
  border: none;
  width: 112px;
  background:url(images/list.png);
  background-position: 0 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 185px;
}
#access ul ul ul a{
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.sub-menu .menu-item-object-custom a:hover{
  height: 40px;
}
#access ul ul a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBEC0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  width: 237px;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

#access ul ul  > a {
  color: #000;
}

#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#access ul ul  .current_page_item > a {
  color: #00ADEE;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#access .current-menu-item > a,
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: elaborate your illustration a bit more . . It's too confusing

Comment: Actually this nothing but a dropdown menu in wordpress twenty eleven theme and the dropdown menu like the above. The First dark aera is the first dropdown menu and the main menu part is the above of all dark area. " Home | About | Contact ". The second dark area is the default output and the third dark area is the output which i want. I want third dark area type dropdown menu should display, when i hover  on the "About" menu.

Comment: i dont see any differences between second and third dark area . .

Comment: Hey coosal i already described that the second one is the state when i hover on the "History" Sub-menu and the third state is when i hover on "About" menu. Which i want, So the second and the third is same, but when you hover on the sub menu History it show like the second area, but i want when i hover on "About" menu it display like the second. Absolutely the second and third is same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to find the rule where there is a :hover defined on a li element. It usually goes like this:

```
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

for the second level menu to be visible, you'd need to add something like the following:

```
li:hover ul ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This is just how it should be in theory, I'd need to see the part of the CSS that describes the menu so I could tell you an exact change to make.

Comment: You're welcome.
If an answer to your question helped, accept it. If however you managed to solve the problem on your own, write it down and accept it as the answer, so that people who search for the same issue know how it's solved.

Comment: Thank you Lazar Vuckovic. I had to display the menu as the third dark area as i mentioned. Now i just add line of code in css file of twenty elecen. like this bellow . If it is wrong then suggest me.#access ul li:hover > ul li ul,
#access ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

Comment: Yes, that would be the principle I described in the answer. Please accept it.